# Looking for a way to get to MS Access 2016+ from a Java 15 or 17 JRE

Tags: java, ms-access-2016

We have just deployed a new batch of computers, all 64-bit Windows 11 compatible, using 64-bit Office applications (so MS Access 2016). I am trying to get our Java applications to get at the database but cannot find a working driver. The old 2010 redistributable, which worked prior to Access 2016 no longer functions because of a BitInteger in the database. The ucan driver at SourceForge is not compatible any longer (limited to Access 2013), so that's out. Short of going with a local MSSQL database, do I have any options? We have also tried migration to C#, but that seems to only support 32-bit MS drivers and won't work in our 64-bit Office environment.

Comment: Look at the ucan driver again. "Supported Access formats: 2000, 2002/2003, 2007, 2010/2013/2016 databases. (Access 97 format supported for read-only.)"

Comment: Describe the exact error that the scan driver gives you, with a short program to reproduce it.

Comment: That's awesome actually. I checked this morning, and it only went to 2013. Will download again and retry tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does work with Access 2016! Huzzah! Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The root cause is that the ucanaccess repo README is out of date and does not list 2016. It does work, although the integration is not perfect. Access does not recognize completed INSERT operations until Access is restarted - at least for some tables. I will take this up with the author.